# Express js routing error ("Cannot GET /")

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am having a hard time wondering why, when i access my HTTP server http://localhost:8000/, i get a "Cannot GET /" message. I use express js for routing server side and angular at client-side.

I have read that this error is there because i haven't set a route for "/" path, but i don't want to route anything there, just want to let my angular handle "/".

FYI, my express server is in a different path than the angular app.

MY node code:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var express = require('express');
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var moment = require('moment');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');
var compress = require('compression');

var config = require('./config');

var User = mongoose.model('User', new mongoose.Schema({
  instagramId: { type: String, index: true },
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  password: { type: String, select: false },
  username: String,
  fullName: String,
  picture: String,
  accessToken: String
}));

mongoose.connect(config.db);

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);
app.use(compress());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { maxAge: 2628000000 }));

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Login Required Middleware
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (!(req.headers && req.headers.authorization)) {
    return res.status(400).send({ message: 'You did not provide a JSON Web Token in the Authorization header.' });
  }

  var header = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');
  var token = header[1];
  var payload = jwt.decode(token, config.tokenSecret);
  var now = moment().unix();

  if (now > payload.exp) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Token has expired.' });
  }

  User.findById(payload.sub, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: 'User no longer exists.' });
    }

    req.user = user;
    next();
  })
}

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Generate JSON Web Token
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function createToken(user) {
  var payload = {
    exp: moment().add(14, 'days').unix(),
    iat: moment().unix(),
    sub: user._id
  };

  return jwt.encode(payload, config.tokenSecret);
}

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Sign in with Email
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/auth/login', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, '+password', function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).send({ message: { email: 'Incorrect email' } });
    }

    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if (!isMatch) {
        return res.status(401).send({ message: { password: 'Incorrect password' } });
      }

      user = user.toObject();
      delete user.password;

      var token = createToken(user);
      res.send({ token: token, user: user });
    });
  });
});

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Create Email and Password Account
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/auth/signup', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, existingUser) {
    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(409).send({ message: 'Email is already taken.' });
    }

    var user = new User({
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    });

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
      bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
        user.password = hash;

        user.save(function() {
          var token = createToken(user);
          res.send({ token: token, user: user });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Sign in with Instagram
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/auth/instagram', function(req, res) {
  var accessTokenUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';

  var params = {
    client_id: req.body.clientId,
    redirect_uri: req.body.redirectUri,
    client_secret: config.clientSecret,
    code: req.body.code,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
  };

  // Step 1. Exchange authorization code for access token.
  request.post({ url: accessTokenUrl, form: params, json: true }, function(error, response, body) {

    // Step 2a. Link user accounts.
    if (req.headers.authorization) {

      User.findOne({ instagramId: body.user.id }, function(err, existingUser) {

        var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        var payload = jwt.decode(token, config.tokenSecret);

        User.findById(payload.sub, '+password', function(err, localUser) {
          if (!localUser) {
            return res.status(400).send({ message: 'User not found.' });
          }

          // Merge two accounts. Instagram account takes precedence. Email account is deleted.
          if (existingUser) {

            existingUser.email = localUser.email;
            existingUser.password = localUser.password;

            localUser.remove();

            existingUser.save(function() {
              var token = createToken(existingUser);
              return res.send({ token: token, user: existingUser });
            });

          } else {
            // Link current email account with the Instagram profile information.
            localUser.instagramId = body.user.id;
            localUser.username = body.user.username;
            localUser.fullName = body.user.full_name;
            localUser.picture = body.user.profile_picture;
            localUser.accessToken = body.access_token;

            localUser.save(function() {
              var token = createToken(localUser);
              res.send({ token: token, user: localUser });
            });

          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      // Step 2b. Create a new user account or return an existing one.
      User.findOne({ instagramId: body.user.id }, function(err, existingUser) {
        if (existingUser) {
          var token = createToken(existingUser);
          return res.send({ token: token, user: existingUser });
        }

        var user = new User({
          instagramId: body.user.id,
          username: body.user.username,
          fullName: body.user.full_name,
          picture: body.user.profile_picture,
          accessToken: body.access_token
        });

        user.save(function() {
          var token = createToken(user);
          res.send({ token: token, user: user });
        });
      });
    }
  });
});

app.get('/api/feed', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  var feedUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed';
  var params = { access_token: req.user.accessToken };

  request.get({ url: feedUrl, qs: params, json: true }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      res.send(body.data);
    }
  });
});

app.get('/api/media/:id', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  var mediaUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/' + req.params.id;
  var params = { access_token: req.user.accessToken };

  request.get({ url: mediaUrl, qs: params, json: true }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      res.send(body.data);
    }
  });
});

app.post('/api/like', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  var mediaId = req.body.mediaId;
  var accessToken = { access_token: req.user.accessToken };
  var likeUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/' + mediaId + '/likes';

  request.post({ url: likeUrl, form: accessToken, json: true }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
      return res.status(response.statusCode).send({
        code: response.statusCode,
        message: body.meta.error_message
      });
    }
    res.status(200).end();
  });
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Angular for your web app, you would want your express server to serve all the files related to the front-end so when you land on the link "http://localhost:8000/", Express would serve the related files back. This folder would include .js, .css and .html files as well as all the other resources (images, videos etc.) so you can link them in your markup. (eg link href="/logo.png").

You can serve these files using Express by telling express to use the [Static Middleware](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html).

Using the Middleware, you would tell Express to serve the contents of a specific folder as static resources. Putting your Angular App in the folder would then let Angular handle the routes.

```
var publicFolder = path.join(__dirname, '../client')
app.use(express.static(publicFolder);
```

You would register other endpoints to create an API for your web app. So express server would be able to provide data to the Angular app through those endpoints.

Answer (score 4):

In that case, then you should catch all the routes in / to angular.

Put this code at the very last of your route definitions before error handlers.

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/path/to/angular/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. i used app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));